# Ruby gem for cloning a subset of production database records

Tags: ruby, database, dump

Time ago I discovered a ruby gem that allows you to create database dumps with particular rules.

Inside a file you defined wich tables to dump, which records to skip and which fields to scramble in a nifty ruby DSL.

I can't remember the name of the tool, do you know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

After searching for an hour I finally found it. 
It's called *ocelot*, here is the homepage: http://exussum.heroku.com/projects/ocelot